# How is IDM And Flashget,... are working? (maximum speed download)

Tags: c#, sockets, download

I need to download with maximum available download speed in C#.

FlashGet, IDM and other download managers seem to be able to.

Answer (score 3):

It's nothing special, they're simply opening up multiple download connections to the same file and use segmented downloading so each connection pulls down a different range of bytes from the file.

For more information see for example - http://www.ehow.com/how-does_4615524_download-accelerator-work.html

For the C# side you might want to look at existing .NET projects such as this - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21053/MyDownloader-A-Multi-thread-C-Segmented-Download-M

Comment: I saw MyDownloader before, is slower than flashget. I think is something more.

Comment: Not really, probably just a limitation in the implementation of MyDownloader.

Answer (score 3):

The magic is in **multiple connection** and http **`Range` header**.

Say a file is 100MB in size. You plan to open 10 connections. So for each connections you'll download 10Mb. Now open a http connection and start downloading same file but 10 connecitons will be assigned to 10 different segments.

Connection 1 sends `Range: bytes=0-1048575`

Connection 2 sends `Range: bytes=1048576-2097151`

and so on

Answer (score 1):

You have to set Window size in TCP protocol. but this future is not support in .net